# Convergence of the central limit theorem: pointwise vs uniform convergence

Tags: probability, uniform-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots $ be a sequence of iid real random variables with finite moments (assume mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$) and call $X=\frac1N \sum_i X_i$.

The central limit theorem tells us that the distribution of $Z=\sqrt{N}(X-\mu)/\sigma$ converges in distribution to the normal law $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. This means that the cumulative distribution function, $F_N(z)=P_N(Z\leq z)$ converges to that of the normal $\Phi(z)$,
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} F_N(z)\to \Phi(z).
$$
By the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem), we know that this convergence is uniform in $z$.

My question concerns the convergence of the probability density itself $P_N(Z=z)$ (and not the cumulative distribution function). Assuming that $P_N$ converges, it will converge to the Gaussian. But how does it converge? Only pointwise or can it be uniformly, and what are the conditions?

For instance, if the $X_i$ are uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, it is not hard to convince oneself that the convergence is uniform, as the difference between $P_N$ and a Gaussian is of order $1/N^{3/2}$ at most. On the other hand, if the $X_i$ are exponential random variables, then the convergence is only pointwise, and there is some kind of Gibbs-like phenomenon where the distance to a Gaussian is always of order $0.18$ for some $z$ for any $N$, see for example the figures [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/06/01/clt-runge/comment-page-1/?unapproved=1146972&moderation-hash=271f65cbd33e225820268e7eee46eb72).

What are the criterions to discriminate between the two convergences here?

Comment: Binomial distribution does not have a density.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sure. But that's not the problem here. I remove the term "density".

Comment: @Adam but if the binomial does not have a density then what does *"For instance, if $P_N$ is a binomial, it is not hard to convince oneself that the convergence is uniform, as the difference between that and a Gaussian is of order $1/\sqrt{N}$ at most"* mean? What difference are you looking at?

Comment: @Henry I gave an example using a continuous variable so that this irrelevant aspect does not get into the way.

Comment: Also worth noting that John D. Cook's difference is between the density of the average of exponential random variables and the approximating normal distribution. The peak of the density goes up with the number being averaged and a constant maximum difference looks relatively small.  The central limit theorem involves rescaling, and if you rescale (and relocate) the gamma distribution in a CLT sense then you get the maximum difference in density diminishing towards $0$ as the number of random variables increases

Comment: @Henry I do not think so. You can generate the plot with this Mathematica line:
ListLinePlot[ Table[{x, (E^(-n x) (n x)^n)/(x Gamma[n]) - E^(-(1/2) n (-1 + x)^2)/ 
     Sqrt[2 \[Pi]/n] /. n -> 10000}, {x, 3/4, 1 + 1/4, 10^-3}],  PlotRange -> All]
The first function is the distribution of the sum (X in the post) of those exponentially distributed X_i with mean 1. The second is the gaussian. The position of the maximum of the difference is about $1\pm 1/\sqrt{N}$, but its value is always finite $\simeq \frac{13}{15 \sqrt[5]{e} \sqrt{5 \pi }}$. It looks like a Gibbs phenomenon.

Comment: What *is* $P_N(z)$?  You have not defined this notation, and it is not clear what you mean by "the probability itself".  Exactly what event is it supposed to be the probability of?  Or do you actually mean the *probability density function* of the random variable $X$ (whose values are not in fact the probability of anything)?

Comment: You might get somewhere by looking at Fourier transforms...

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, the probability density $P_N(Z=z)$, i.e. the probability that the random variable $Z$ takes the value $z$. I don't see how the Fourier transform would help here (my question has nothing to do with the Gibbs phenomenon appearing with Fourier series).

Comment: For instance, if the Fourier transforms converge in $L^1$, then the densities converge uniformly.

Comment: What your code seems to show is $\frac{e^{-nx}(nx)^n}{x\Gamma(n)} - \frac{e^{-n(x-1)^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi/n}}$ where $x$ is the sum of $n$ exponential random variables with mean $1$.  But that right hand term is not a limiting density: it depends on $n$.  The Central Limit theorem is about the limiting distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\bar X -\mu)$ or equivalently about $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum X_i-\sqrt{n}\mu$.  ...

Comment: ... So the difference in densities for this (rescaled and relocated) gamma distribution for $x=\sqrt{n}(\bar X -\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum X_i-\sqrt{n}\mu$ and the CLT limiting distribution should be something like $\dfrac{\sqrt n e^{-(\sqrt n x+n)}(\sqrt n x+n)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)} - \dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ with the right hand term not depending on $n$. The maximum difference would then be $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.  I might expect a similar thing with iid uniform random variables.

Comment: @Henry Yes, you are right, I realized that yesterday evening... But is this always true that the convergence is uniform?

Comment: I would expect it to be true for "well behaved" cases - we know this excludes discrete distributions and Cantor distributions where the sums or averages do not have a density at all.  The CLT requires a finite variance, so you might want to look at cases where the distribution has no third moment or unbounded density - my guess without checking is that it could work for these too

Comment: @Henry : just for completeness, what I was aiming for in the case discrete random variables (which do not have densities) is treated in Koralov and Sinai's book (Theory of probability and random processes (2007, Springer)), Th 10.10. It shows that the distribution of the sum of such variables converges uniformly to a Gaussian.

Comment: @Adam - That is presumably a statement about the CDF (after suitable relocation and scaling).   The interesting questions for me are (a) relative rather than absolute errors, especially in the tails and (b) errors using an Gaussian density to approximate the probability mass function of a sum of equally spaced discrete random variables (e.g. supported solely on integers)

Comment: @Henry : no, it is a statement about the probability itself (at integer values of the sum).

Comment: @Adam: Consider (a) $X_i$ iid with $\mathbb P(X_i=0)=0.6$,  $\mathbb P(X_i=2)=\mathbb P(X_i=1)=\mathbb P(X_i=-1)=\mathbb P(X_i=-2)=0.1$ compared to (b) $Y_j$ iid with $\mathbb P(Y_j=1)=\mathbb P(Y_j=-1)=0.5$, $\mathbb P(Y_j=2)=\mathbb P(Y_j=0)=\mathbb P(Y_j=-2)=0$.  Both have mean $0$ and variance $1$, so the CDFs of their rescaled sums or averages converge to the same normal distribution, but the probability mass functions of the sums are always substantially different: $\mathbb P(\sum_1^n Y_j =k)$ often about $2$ or $0$ times  $\mathbb P(\sum_1^n X_i =k)$.

Comment: @Henry: what I meant is the following. For both random variables, the PDF of the sum converges to the gaussian (restricted to the discrete values $k$). This can be easily checked on your example (one can also compute the corrections to the gaussian in an expansion in $1/\sqrt{n}$ explicitly as polynomials time a gaussian.

Comment: I do not understand "For both random variables, the PDF of the sum converges to the gaussian (restricted to the discrete values $k$)."  A finite sum of discrete random variables will never have a density. To take my example, $\mathbb P(\sum_1^{100} X_i =6) \approx 0.033$ and $\mathbb P(\sum_1^{100} X_i =7) \approx 0.031$ while $\mathbb P(\sum_1^{100} Y_j =6) \approx 0.067$ and $\mathbb P(\sum_1^{100} Y_j =7) = 0$ although they have the same Gaussian approximation to the CDF of $\mathcal N(0,100)$

Comment: @Henry: the factor of 2 is somewhat "trivial", it comes from the fact that $Y=\sum_i Y_i$ changes by steps of 2, and so you must morally "absorb" a factor of 2 is a wannabe $dy$ when converging to the gaussian. Another way to put it is that if you think in terms of histograms, those of $Y$ are rectangles of area $2*P(Y=k)$  while those of $X$ have area $2*P(X=k)$. You can check easily that the $P(Y=k)$ and $P(X=k)$ are well described by $exp(-k^2/(2N))/\sqrt{2\pi N}$ (up to this factor 2 for $Y$) for $N$ large enough, as claimed.

Comment: I would not say that any multiplicative constant other than $1$ was trivial.  You also have the issue that $ \mathbb P(\sum_1^{n} Y_j =k)$ depends fundamentally on the relative parities of $n$ and $k$.  If the support of your underlying discrete random variable was not in a sense equally spaced, e.g. $P(Z_i=-1)=1-\sqrt{\frac12}, P(Z_i=0)=\frac12, P(Z_i=\sqrt 2)=\sqrt{\frac12}-\frac12$ then it would become even stranger.  I think you are hoping for too much from discrete random variables.